# Email sent to an address from a csv file in Talend (one time)

Tags: email, parsing, etl, talend

I need to send an email using Talend however using I need to have the address captured from a csv file. (automated each time and not specified manually)

Right now I can only add an email address manually. I need Talend to capture it from the csv file and also I need it to send once and not many times (right now as long as the query is running it send many emails)

Comment: show us what you tried. you can add multiple e-mails divided by commas or ; you can create a list using tAggregateRow

Comment: I have twaitforfile -> tflowtoiterate -> tfileinputdelimited -> tmap_1 -> tbdoutput ->tsendemail    What I want to do is get the email from the tfileinputdelimited, I dont know the email ahead of time thats why I can't add a predefined list. It all depends on the new file added and detected by the file watcher

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are after but this is my suggestion:
[image]

The tSetGlobalVar component simply initializes the variables like this:

[image]

Then the tMap supplies the t_Java_Row with the e-mail from the file (I am assuming that is where it is - you didn't specify).  The code in the tMap sets the values of the global variables with this code (in the code section of the tJava_Row component)

globalMap.put("email", input_row.email);

globalMap.put("body", input_row.body);

Then in the send mail component you recall the variables that were set.
[image]

Hope there is enough in there to help a bit.  There might be other ways to do this, but that would be my approach.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, before tfileinputdelimited I have a connection from iterate, since I want a file watcher to check the directory for new files. Now if I wanna add the tsetglobalvar, I can't connect it to tfileinputdelimited, since its already connected to titerate

Comment: in your job the tSetGlobalVariiable should go before the tWaitForFile.  Its function is only to initialize the global variables.